Generating Signed URL for Replit Object Storage Bucket using GCS client libraries
I'm using replit object storage, which is a wrapper of GCS(google cloud storage). Replit does provide a library to upload and download objects, but that library isn't very flexible. Replit handles authentication and integrates with google application default credentials. One can do it by adding
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "replit",
  "credential_source": {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:1106/credential"
  },
  "token_url": "http://127.0.0.1:1106/token"
}

to google_application_credentials.json in the root directory of the project. I was able to successfully upload a file directly using GCS client libraries, however I'm unable to generate a signed URL for customised access. I get the following error
Upload error: Error: Cannot sign data without `client_email`.
    at GoogleAuth.sign 

This is my code.
const storage = new Storage({
      credentials: {
        type: "external_account",
        audience: "replit",
        credential_source: {
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:1106/credential",
        },
        token_url: "http://127.0.0.1:1106/token",
      },
    });


const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const blob = bucket.file(filename);

 const [signedUrl] = await blob.getSignedUrl({
      action: "read",
      expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // URL expires in 15 minutes
    });

Is it possible to generate a signed url ? If not how can I make the entire bucket public using GCS client libraries ? Any help would be appreciated.

As suggested here try  updating the library version also check this link
